# How can a field in the Django admin panel be made writable for a model only when it is being created, and it'll be read only at other times?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on a project similar to a stock market. In this project I have a model called `Stock` which is as follows:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    _title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    _description = models.TextField()
    _total_subs = models.IntegerField()
    _sold_out_subs = models.IntegerField()
    _created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    _status = models.BooleanField()
```

Access to create new records for this model is to be supposed only through the Django admin panel, so in the admin.py file in my app I wrote a class to manage it called StockAdmin as follows:

```
class StockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = []
    readonly_fields = ['_sold_out_subs']
    
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
```

How can I make a `_total_subs` so that it can be writable when it being create and then  it should be in read-only fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get readonly fields based on object like this

```
class StockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = []

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
       if obj:
           return ['_sold_out_subs']
       else:
           return []
```

besides that its not good django practice to start field names with underscore since they imply that the field is a private.
check this answer for more info
[What is the meaning of single and double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)

Answer (score 1):

By adding `list_editable = []` add all fields you have except `_total_subs`

Answer (score 0):

Use **`get_readonly_fields`** method

```py
class StockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return ['_sold_out_subs'] if obj else []
```